# where is 960-fluid-rtl.css?

Tags: css, drupal, right-to-left, 960.gs

I configure Drupal Omega theme to be fluid and rtl, but 960 GS dose not support rtl layout in fluid mod.

where can I find 960-fluid-rtl.css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply copy/past 960-fluid.css and rename to 960-fluid-rtl.css, clear styles except push and pull styles and swap .push and .pull styles.

```
find and replace:
.push->.xxxx
.pull->.push
.xxxx->.pull
```

and some hack to template.php

```
function omega_css_alter(&$css) {
    // fluid width option
    if (theme_get_setting('omega_fixed_fluid') == 'fluid') {
        $css_960 = drupal_get_path('theme', 'omega') . '/css/960.css';
        $css_960_rtl = drupal_get_path('theme', 'omega') . '/css/960-rtl.css';
        if (isset($css[$css_960])) {
            $css[$css_960]['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'omega') . '/css/960-fluid.css';
        }
        if (isset($css[$css_960_rtl])) {
            $css[$css_960_rtl]['data'] = drupal_get_path('theme', 'omega') . '/css/960-fluid-rtl.css';
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an [old open issue](http://drupal.org/node/849718) that sounds like what you're describing. Maybe this is actually just broken at the moment?